# A command is working in CMD but not working in c++ program using system() function

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2013

I'm trying to run CMD commands from a C++ program, but some of the commands are working properly in CMD but not working in the C++ program. For example, `btdiscovery -s` is working in CMD, but not as `system("btdiscovery -s")` from my C++ program. The error is:

> 'btdiscovery' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Why would this be happening, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to check would be whether the PATH of the hosted (shelled) process contains the executable you're attempting to fire. Alternatively, you could provide a full path to the executable in the launching code.

Comment: It is working in CMD of Windows so it's supposed to run in system command to as system simply send command to CMD isn't it?

Comment: A shelled process may have slightly different environment variables than a command prompt. A fully qualified path to the target executable would probably be the safest choic.

Comment: How can is provide full path?

Comment: In the code that launches your app, btdiscovery, simply provide the full path to it instead, eg c:\somefolder\bt\btdiscovery.exe (changing the path as appropriate for its actual location on your machine). If you are firing the app with CreateProcess, I believe the first argument is an optional pathspec and the second is the executable itself...

Comment: Great! Glad to help.